# select * from table where id = select max id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to get data where id = last id in table and show all value not one value ?

I have table name=tb_invoice and 3 column (id, month, year)
How to get last id and show result (id, month, year) in codeigniter?
here my code :

```
    $this->db->select_max('id');
    $query  = $this->db->get('tb_invoice');
    return  = $query->row_array();
```

the result just show id, how to show all value (id, month, year)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$this->db->select('id, month, year')->order_by('id','desc')->limit(1)->get('tb_invoice')->row('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using insert_id.

```
$this->db->insert_id();
$query  = $this->db->get('tb_invoice');
return  = $query->row_array();
```

Or you can use

```
$this->db->select_max('{primary key}');
$query  = $this->db->get('tb_invoice');
return  = $query->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

```
$maxid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `tb_invoice`')->row()->maxid;
```

UPDATE

This will work even if your table is empty (unlike my example above):

```
$maxid = 0;
$row = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `tb_invoice`')->row();
if ($row) {
    $maxid = $row->maxid; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Sunny Khatri for code,
this is worked:

```
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$query  = $this->db->get('tb_invoice');
return $query->row_array();
```